# MYSQL LIKE on 2 columns?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called users, which as 2 columns `forename` and `surname`

i have created a search input, and wondered how i can join the forename and surname column when searching.

For example if my table has the forename `Johnny` and the surname `Bishop`

if the user searched for Johnny or Bishop then it will show the result, however if the user types the full name - `Johnny Bishop` no results show.

My SQL looks like

```
AND u.forename LIKE '%$name%' OR u.surname LIKE '%$name%' OR u.email = '$name'
```

Comment: Expand the question to show how `Johnny Bishop` should be searched.

Comment: you could build a php function that extracts de forename

Comment: Side note: Learn to use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use `CONCAT()` to concatenate forename and username and search  based on the result.

```
AND u.forename LIKE '%$name%' 
OR u.surname LIKE '%$name%' 
OR CONCAT(u.`forename`, " ",u.`surname`) LIKE '%$name%' 
OR u.email = '$name'
```

If you want to include cases where the user typed multiple white spaces you could use `REPLACE()` to remove all whitespaces

```
OR REPLACE(CONCAT(u.`forename`,u.`lastname`),' ','') LIKE CONCAT('%',REPLACE('$name',' ',''),'%')
```